# how can i build proxy classes from wsdl( wcf services) in android?

Tags: android, wcf, wsdl

I need to build proxy from a "WSDL" to call "WCF" services.
please provide me info. about tolls required and steps to do.

i have wsdl document.
and want to create a android client to consume the services.

i have spend a lot time on tht.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Android doesn't have built in SOAP API. You must use some additional library like [kSoap2](http://code.google.com/p/ksoap2-android/) but those libraries doesn't provide automatic client generation - [you must code it](http://seesharpgears.blogspot.com/2010/11/basic-ksoap-android-tutorial.html). There are products which are able to generate clients but I expect them to be commercial like [WSClient++](http://wsclient.neurospeech.com/).

Comment: thanks a lot. i got this . i have to parse the result from xml.. is there any tool which is open source for client generation.